# Use keras ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() with Talos Scan()

Tags: python, keras, talos

Talos is a module that allows you to do hyperparameter tuning on keras models you've already written code for. The conventional way it is used in examples is with the `Scan` class which is instantiated with `x` and `y` parameters. These parameters should contain an array with training data and labels respectively.

```
def modelbuilder(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, params):
    # modelbuilding 
    out = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    return model, out

talos.Scan(x, y, params=params, model=modelbuilder)
```

However Keras provides a second way to import data with the `ImageDataGenerator` class, in stead of an array you just need a directory with the train/validation images.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Its unclear to me how I can `Scan` this, the datageneration should contains a hyperparameter (batch size) which should be inside the `modelbuilder` function. But at the same time `Scan` requires data arguments to be provided as an array. Any suggestion how I can combine Talos with the ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: I don't know about Talos, but I doubt current version of Talos support `fit_generator`: https://github.com/autonomio/talos/issues/11. If you have enough memory space, you can try loading all the data into memory and use `model.fit`. From the [Talos README](https://github.com/autonomio/talos), you can actually pass batch_size as hyperparam but you have to use `model.fit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use fit_generator() in Talos experiments. See the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/autonomio/talos/issues/11) for more information.

There is no specific instructions pertaining to "how to" as in accord with Talos philosophy you can use fit_generator exactly the way you would use it with a standalone Keras model. Just replace `model.fit(...)` with `model.fit_generator(...)` and use a generator as per your need.