# Combination of all parameters for grid search

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid-search

I'm training a FastText word-representation model, and I'm performing a grid search over a range of multiple parameters. Below is multiple parameter lists:

```
wordNgrams = [2, 3, 4, 5]
lr = [10e-2, 10e-3, 10e-4, 10e-5, 10e-6]
dim = [200, 250, 300]
ws = [5, 6, 8, 10]
```

I'd like to try every possible combination for the above lists together and pass them as parameters to train my model. I don't know how to implement a python function to do that and was hoping for some help. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product
print(product(wordNgrams, lr, dim, ws,repeat=4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted clarification on the repeat parameter, what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Sam Your welcome, `repeat` means how many values per subtuple.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ParameterGrid from sklearn.model_selection. Explained better in answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58834553/2006413).